# Fall back to begining of string in RegEx

Tags: php, regex

Is it possible to have a RegEx fall back to the beginning of the string and begin matching again?

Here's why I ask. Given the below string, I'd like to capture the sub strings `black`, `red`, `blue`, and `green` in that order, regardless of the order of occurrence in the subject string and only if all substrings are present in the subject string.

`$str ='blue-ka93-red-kdke3-green-weifk-black'`

So, for all of the below strings, the RegEx should capture `black`, `red`, `blue`, and `green` (in that order)

```
'blue-ka93-red-kdke3-green-weifk-black'
'green-ka93-red-kdke3-blue-weifk-black'
'blue-ka93-black-kdke3-green-weifk-red'
'green-ka93-black-kdke3-blue-weifk-red'
```

I wonder if there isn't a way to match a capture group then fall back to the start of the string and find the next capture group. I was hoping that something like `^.*(?=(black))^.*(?=(red))^.*(?=(blue))^.*(?=(green))` would work but of course the `^` and lookaheads do not behave this way.

Is it possible to construct such a RegEx?

*For context, I'll be using the RegEx in PHP.*

Comment: Like this: [`^(?=.*(black))(?=.*(red))(?=.*(blue))(?=.*(green))`](https://regex101.com/r/qB0bR5/1)? This will require all these keywords to be in the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yep, exactly like that, throw that up as an answer and I'll accept it, thank you!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Please elaborate each step in your answer.

Comment: @DelightedD0D: What problem is this kind of **`fallback`** solving ?

Comment: @noob that should be pretty clear from the question ;)

Comment: @noob however, if you're curious, in my actual use case, I need to parse out 4 parameters (check in and out date fragments) from a url where those parameters might be listed in any order, but I need to ensure that I collect them in a specific order so that I can manipulate them from there see this [php fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/x1v2-nbzb) for my actual regex using the solution below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?=.*(black))(?=.*(red))(?=.*(blue))(?=.*(green))
```

**Note: This will require all these keywords to be in the string.**

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qB0bR5/1)

There is no way to reset RegEx index when matching, so, you can only use capturing mechanism inside a positive lookahead anchored at the start. The lookahead will match an empty location at the start of the string (due to `^`) and each of tose lookaheads in the RegEx above will be executed one after another if the previous one returned true (found a string of text meeting its pattern).

Your RegEx did not work the same way because you matched, consumed the text with`.*` (this subpattern was outside the lookaheads) and repeated the start of string anchor that automatically fails a RegEx if you do not use a multiline modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for maintaining the order.

```
^(?:(black)|(red)|(blue)|(green)|.)+$
```

This will match any string, all colors are optional.

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qK5hY2/1) or [php demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/510662)

Comment: I actually need to ensure that all patterns are present in my current useage but +1 for an awesome optional match solution