# Postgresql cut last few chars of string and paste it to the beginning

Tags: regex, postgresql

Suppose I have the following strings:

- test_id
- anything
- other_id
- xyz_id
- example

I need to create a Regex that searches for `_id`, removes it from the end and paste `id_` in the beginning, resulting in:

- id_test
- anything
- id_other
- id_xyz
- example

Is there a way I can do this in a SELECT or in the last case use a function?

Comment: You can match for `_` and `id` as separate groups and replace the beginning by `positioning`. Have you tried anything ?

Comment: @noob I was thinking of using `regex_replace` but I only know how to replace the pattern searched, what I want is to search for something and change other part of the string. I was not aware of `position` function.

Comment: It's not a function. It's a technique using `look around` assertions. I have posted my answer.

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted?

Comment: I don't know. To me this is a good question. Maybe because you forgot to mention your attempt to solve it.

Comment: `select case when 'foo_id' like '%\_id' then 'id_' || substring('foo_id' from '(.*)\_id') else 'foo_id' end;` where `like '%\_id'` checks is string ended by `_id` (note that _ character escaped by backslash because normally it meaning any character in the `like` template) and `substring('foo_id' from '(.*)\_id')` returns characters before `_id` and it can be replaced by `substring('foo_id' from 1 for length('foo_id') - 3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is inspired from [Wiktor Stribiżew's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111272/fall-back-to-begining-of-string-in-regex) questions. More explanation about the regex could be found there.

So here is the regex which cuts the characters from string and paste them at beginning.

**Regex**: `/^(?=.*(_))(?=.*(id))/gm`

**Explanation**: It searches for `_` and `id` and return regex pointer to beginning.

**<kbd>[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oD9gZ8/5)</kbd>**

This will result in string to be like `id_test_id`. The trailing part is still intact which can be replaced by a simple regex like this.

**Regex**: `/_id$/gm`

**Explanation**: It searches for `_id` from the end of each line.

Then substitute by `nothing`.

**<kbd>[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oD9gZ8/4)</kbd>**